# How to use win32 extensions from network location for python

Tags: python, windows, networking, pywin32, maya

We have huge number of system running Win XP and win 7.

We will be having Python x32 and x64 on systems. And the required modules (like PyQt4,win32,etc) are kept in the central location from where all can access those modules.

Modules are kept in different folders as per x32 and x64.

**x32 Python**

\\share\Python26_x32

**x32 modules are kept at**

\\share\modules\x32

**x64 Python**

\\share\Python26_x64

**x64 modules are kept at**

\\share\modules\x64

All modules are working fine from network location. But i need to run 
`\\share\Python26_x32\python.exe \\share\\Python26_x32\Scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py -install` on every system for win32 modules to work.

I have a situation where local python will be x32 and Maya x64. if i run the post script for x32, win32 modules won't import in Maya x64.

is there any alternate to use win32 without running postinstall script for win32 modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last after a long try I could able to manage this issue.

As i said i installed Python x32 and Maya x64.

After installation of Python x32 i executed `\\share\Python26_x32\python.exe \\share\\Python26_x32\Scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py -install`

After that i copied `x64 pywin32 dlls` from `\\share\modules\x64\pywin32_system32`

```
pythoncom26.dll
pythoncomloader26.dll
pywintypes26.dll
```

to `%SystemRoot%\system32`

And this solved my issue with python x32 having maya x64